# Reading From Text File breaks midway

Tags: vbscript

Resolved: All I had to do was add a sleep to the loop.

I have a text file which contains usernames and passwords which need to be logged in. I'm attempting to make a VBScript file to automate this process. The text file's syntax is

```
    username
    password
    username
    password
    etc etc
```

and is a total of 738 lines.

The code I currently have is

```
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Jacob\Desktop\logins.txt", ForReading)
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Const ForReading = 1
    Dim strUsername
    Dim strPassword
    wshshell.AppActivate "Notepad"
    Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strUsername = objFile.ReadLine
    strPassword = objFile.ReadLine
    wshshell.sendkeys strUsername
    wshshell.sendkeys "~"
    wshshell.sendkeys strPassword
    wshshell.sendkeys "~"
    Loop
```

which I'm using simply to make sure it works by having it write to a blank text file. (Later notepad will be replaced by the login executable, I already know that part works).

The code works fine until it hits line 221 of the text file, where it breaks. It exports a bunch of random garbage and then stops.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Here is the garbage text which comes at the end of the written text file. You can see that there are still remnants of what should come out.

.[redacted username].22bssddd2222ent000.2wlllkarsstt00....000h8b6b99b88uub2

.....ttttte0000mp00...gh.rrlll00225..gbu
.....0022sdg
[redacted password]
.proeflussssddd
..22le.pu6....225500s.gl.iteee.55.uuu.hmadttn..0dl

tsssssbeeee0000nsssss0000000ssssdssdbuuuz22dddd000buuu.jj2222
b4....3
.j00000000b

y.

bb.ddddssgg.2222ssgg05uuudbeeeeen......hh00222l11.....tdddd.nn

00000
ll0ssssau0s000ssssss
bbddddlll.ttttl......s
be

.o222

b.ddddddutttt
ll000buc11e000000utttt
bbb.eeeeee0000seeeee5

mmssss000000unnnttttnnn
bb000..s.dsssssss.fa000000
2
.....k000.4tnnn
.....bbbseeeu

.n.2te....s
7e9bbmv00000000tttteeee.mttseetnn2222222r0000000000.u.ddd0000000.111ddddge11111ssddddoo000.ssssssnnnn.uutnnn772
.bbg.......66teeb000000ee1114lrd00002222nsp

Comment: When it stops, it should give you an error code and tell you what line it stopped on. Can you please post this information? Screenshots are always excellent!

Comment: I don't get an error. I'll post a screenshot of what the export spits out, but I'll have to blur out the usernames/passwords that are there.

Comment: Something else to note is that `WshShell.AppActivate` requires the full titlebar description. You only have `"Notepad"` in this, but I suspect you wanted `Untitled - Notepad`. If some other application is stealing focus, it won't return to notepad, and will result in sending the keys elsewhere. Also keep in mind that any of the passwords have characters other numbers and letter such as a plus sign (+), tilde (~), percentage sign (%), carot (^), or curly braces ({}) it will cause unexpected keys to be typed.

Comment: That's not it, the keystrokes are sending to Notepad. It goes just fine through the first 200some lines (this time when I ran it it went to line 231) and then breaks down into garbage, with some remnants of proper syntax. It should read as

.xxxxxxxxxxx.year.students.sdg
5 or 6 digit password

where "xxxxxxxxxxx" is the username. The .year.students.sdg is required for the context for the login executable.

I'll add the garbage it spits out to the original post.

Comment: I modified that comment to include a note about the possible values of passwords, please make sure to look at my revised comment.

Comment: The passwords are all just numbers at this point, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Just as and amusing note, I ran your script in a VM before I noticed the Notepad title thing I mentioned early. It caused the VM to crash because it didn't send the focus to Notepad and executed a program on the desktop 400 times.

Comment: Can you open the task manager and look for multiple instances of `wscript.exe` on the Processes tab when you run your script. I am wondering if something could advertently be running the script twice and causing the jibberish.

Comment: @druciferre There is only one instance of wscript.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you can try...

1. Try adding a call to `WScript.Sleep 100` inside your loop after your call to `SendKeys`.
2. Instead of using `AppActivate` and `SendKeys`, you could try it where the script just  writes the usernames and passwords to another file. This would rule out if the problem is being caused by `SendKeys`. Using `SendKeys` with this much data is fairly dangerous anyways. If anything at all goes wrong with Notepad getting focus and the keys start getting directed to another application it could have some very, very unintentional results.

Here is a modified copy of your script to write to a text file

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("logins.txt", ForReading)
Set objFile2 = objFSO.OpenTextFile("logins2.txt", ForWriting, true)
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
Dim strUsername
Dim strPassword

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strUsername = objFile.ReadLine
    strPassword = objFile.ReadLine
    objFile2.Write strUsername & vbCrLf
    objFile2.Write strPassword & vbCrLf
Loop
```

A couple of stylistic notes as well:

- Define constants before you use them, preferably at the very top of the script. This keeps you and other from having to hunt them down later or thinking they haven't already been defined. It's not a big of a problem in a small script like this, but if you scripts starts getting bigger it could cause you headaches down the road.
- Be consistent with `Dim`'s. You defined `strUsername` and `strPassword` but you didn't define `objFSO`, `objFile`, or `WshShell`. I always recommend using `Option Explicit` to force you to define variables before using them. It helps you keep from making spelling mistakes and saves you a lot of headache in the long run.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work. Ultimately it won't be writing to a file, it will be simulating typing the username/password into a login box. I don't believe the login (Novell) will accept input from a script, hence why I was attempting to simluate keypresses.

Comment: I meant this as more of a troubleshooting step. It will help you determine if the problem is with `SendKeys` or elsewhere.

Comment: I've fixed it! I'll edit the original post. All I had to do was add a half second sleep in the loop.

Comment: I thought I suggested that? I posted so many comments I guess I forgot. Anyways, you should post this a separate answer and accept it instead of editng the question.

Comment: I can't answer for 6 more hours since I just signed up. If you post it I will accept though. Thank you for your help and bearing with my noobishness to stack overflow!

Comment: @user2760041, I modified my answer to include `Sleep`